# Spring MVC using AJAX return page not found

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have create an endpoint to delete a record, yet when i use either POST or GET,  i could not reach to that end point, it always said page not found ,i realized there is weird parameter was appended.
example:

> http://localhost:8080/admin/panel/case/survey/delete/completion/form/0af9518a-8eea-4e69-94a3-3571c3785215?_=1526048495480

this my end point :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete/completion/form/${id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String deleteCompletionForm(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    return String.valueOf(completionFormService.deleteCompletionFormThenLog(id));
}
```

this is my ajax :

```
 $('table').on('click', '.delete', function () {

    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this record!')) {

        var contentPanelId = jQuery(this).attr("id");



        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",

            url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/panel/case/survey/delete/completion/form/" + contentPanelId,

            cache: false,
            timeout: 600000,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
                }
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert("Can not delete the record, please try again!")

            }
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is happening due the **cache** setting you are specifying which will add a timestamp parameter to the URL.

From the Jquery docs (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> **cache** (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp') 
>   Type:
>   Boolean If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be
>   cached by the browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work
>   correctly with HEAD and GET requests. **It works by appending
>   "_={timestamp}"** to the GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for
>   other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL
>   that has already been requested by a GET.

Comment: thanks for your answer , yet removing the cache, did not solve my problem that the page is not found.

Comment: My advice is to log the URL and double check the timestamp parameter is not being added. If it is still there try cleaning the cache of your browser (or try in incognito mode)